# Why does my colorbar not display the colors?

Tags: matplotlib

For sure I'm missing something obvious, but I didn't like very much the color bar that Matplotlib created for me at the end of this example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(50)
xy = x*x[:,None]/200 # 0.000 to 12.005

plt.contourf(xy, levels=100)
plt.contour(xy,levels=12, colors='black').clabel(inline=1, fmt='%.2f')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: colorbars should be colored]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've struggled for a while to convince SO that my title was significant and when I finally found of the 40 char limit I lost my temper.... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change the order of the contours, since `plt` will capture the latest object, and your contour with 12 levels has no colors:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(50)
xy = x*x[:,None]/200 # 0.000 to 12.005

plt.contour(xy, levels=12, colors='black').clabel(inline=1, fmt='%.2f')
plt.contourf(xy, levels=100)
plt.colorbar()
```

**OR:** you can pass a required contour to `plt.colobar()` directly:

```py
...
c = plt.contourf(xy, levels=100)
plt.contour(xy, levels=12, colors='black').clabel(inline=1, fmt='%.2f')
plt.colorbar(c)
```

[image: img]

With the same levels value:

```py
...
plt.contour(xy, levels=12, colors='black').clabel(inline=1, fmt='%.2f')
plt.contourf(xy, levels=12)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: img2]